# Python not returning is directory value

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a directory and output if the current item is a file or a directory. This is the code I am trying to use

```
import os,time

dir = os.listdir("V:\\Inbox/")

for item in dir:
    if os.path.isdir(item):
        print "is Directory"
    else:
        print "is file"
```

Comment: Can you print the content of dir? Are you sure that the path is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the base dir to the path before passing it to `isdir`.

```
import os

basedir = "V:/Inbox/"
dir = os.listdir(basedir)

for item in dir:
    itempath = os.path.join(basedir, item)
    if os.path.isdir(itempath):
        print "is Directory"
    else:
        print "is file"
```

By the way, usually some `print` statements are a good thing to do before posting on SO (even though I don't say no to easy rep from questions like these :P).